# Custom columns in django_tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I've had a search around for this but haven't had much luck so looking for a bit of help. I'm trying to add some extra columns to a table defined by a model, using function definitions in the model. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.TextField()

    def my_function(self):
        # Return some calculated value based on the entry
        return my_value

# tables.py
class MyTable(tables.Table):

    my_extra_column = tables.Column(....)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

# views.py
table = MyTable(MyModel.objects.all())
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request, ....)
```

My question is can I access `my_function` in the entries passed to `MyTable` so I can show the result of `my_function` in the custom `my_extra_column` column? I assume I need to be using accessors, but I can't see how I can access the queryset data using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out in the end, it was actually not too hard after all :)
So using my example above, in order to add a custom column using a function in the associated model you just use [accessors](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#accessor-a) ...

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.TextField()
    my_field_2 = models.IntegerField()

    def my_function(self):
        # Return some calculated value based on the entry
        return my_value

# tables.py
class MyTable(tables.Table):

    my_extra_column = tables.Column(accessor='my_function',
         verbose_name='My calculated value')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['my_field', 'my_field_2', 'my_extra_column']
        model = MyModel
```

The trouble comes if and when you want to be able to sort this data, because the function won't translate into any valid field in `MyModel`. So you could either disable sorting on this column using `ordering=False` or specify a set using `order_by=('field', 'field2')`

Comment: I am also facing a same kind of issue. Can we sort on the basis of the accessor? It does not seem to work. Gives the error that unable to resolve 'name' to a field name.

Comment: Well you could specify ordering on the column using `order_by=('my_field', 'my_field2')` if that worked... otherwise I guess the only way you could really sort using this calculated value would be to create a new field in the model and save it for each entry in the db.

Comment: I don't think storing it directly in DB is a good approach. By order_by do you mean entering order_by in the queryset? Because that gives an error when we to sort on our custom field. 
I followed this issue on Github but it also does not work.
https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/413

Comment: made my day..!...thanx a lot

Comment: [This page in the docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/ordering.html#table-order-foo-methods) gives more information about sorting a custom column.